# Which shebang should I use for F# scripts in Mac OS X?

Tags: f#, shebang

I have F# 2.0 installed with Mono, and I'd like to `./` my F# scripts. Which shebang line should I use for Mac OS X? Can this shebang line be generalized for Mac OS X *and* Linux?

Comment: I think this may be problematic as `#`is not a comment in F# - you may be better writing a simple bash script.  If you are talking about compiled scripts, for linux there is a kernel patch to make `./` work - not sure about for mac

Comment: @JohnPalmer Yes, the lack of `#` comments in F# and other languages makes shebangs more difficult, though not impossible. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang

Comment: that is quite neat - you could hide an entire bash script there which could allow you to do portability stuff

Comment: This is a very neat trick @mcandre--thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, in @mcandre's answer, it works because [most shells revert to bourne shell](https://superuser.com/a/503009/104477) when they don't find a shebang.

So having `#light` which is both valid F# and a comment in bourne shell allows each scripting environment to see what it understands.

The script inside however could be improved. When we execute a script adding `--quiet` to `--exec` seems redundant, also we expect all arguments to be passed to the script. A more ideal version would be `exec fsharpi --exec $0 $*` so all arguments would be passed as if you ran the command explicitly.

`#light` is not the only `#` preceded directive in F#. Preprocessor defines also would work and could be intuitive to what is going on. Putting a shell script between `#if run_with_bin_sh` and `#endif` would be invisible to f# since `run_with_bin_sh` wouldn't be defined.

Example fsx:

```
#if run_with_bin_sh 
  exec fsharpi --exec $0 $*
#endif
printfn "%A" fsi.CommandLineArgs
```

**update:** Real shebang support such as `#!/usr/bin/env fsharpi --exec` has been add into the [official Microsoft F# code base](https://web.archive.org/web/20150518071353/http://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/25). So it should work with future versions of F#.

**update 2:** `#!/usr/bin/env fsharpi --exec` works great for mac, but not on linux. Linux needs to be `#!/usr/bin/fsharpi --exec` [the incompatibilty is annoying.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63979/shebang-line-with-usr-bin-env-command-argument-fails-on-linux)

If you want a cross platform fsharp shebang. The following will work.

```
#!/bin/sh
#if run_with_bin_sh
  exec fsharpi --exec $0 $*
#endif
```

Comment: `/bin/usr/env`??? that looks wrong, is that a typo? I guess you meant `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: In recent versions you don't need the `--exec` parameter anymore, which means that `#!/usr/bin/env fsharpi` now is a cross-platform shebang line.

Answer (score 8):

**NOTE** `fsharpi` has been superseded by `dotnet fsi`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63949598/55246).

---

In Mac OS X, the program is `fsharpi`.

hello.fs:

```
#light (*
    exec fsharpi --exec $0 --quiet
*)

System.Console.WriteLine "Hello World"
```

Comment: I was assuming that the OP was asking about F# scripts (.fsx extension), not F# files (.fs extension)

Answer (score 6):

With the most recent crossplatform .net installed and the most recent linux (coreutil 8.30 <=) and bsd / mac os releases. You can use the following shebang for F# `.fsx` scripts.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env -S dotnet fsi
```